# High resolution canvas of radar chart for pdf file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, html5-canvas, chart.js

I have the given code below for displaying a radar chart using Chart.js. When I display it as PDF on my screen it appears blurry. I've been trying to scale using webkitBackingStorePixelRatio and devicePixelRatio on Chrome, but I'm a little bit stuck.

--HTML--

```
<div class="chart">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
```

--Javascript--

```
<script>

        var ctx1 = document.getElementById("myChart");

        var myRadarChart1 = new Chart(ctx1, {
            type: 'radar',
            data: {
                labels: {{ competenceCleTitle|json_encode|raw }},
                datasets: [
                    {
                        backgroundColor: "#F79646",
                        borderColor: "#f59c1a",
                        pointBackgroundColor: "#f59c1a",
                        pointBorderColor: "#fff",
                        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "#fff",
                        pointHoverBorderColor: "#f59c1a",
                        pointRadius: 0,
                        data: {{ competenceCleNiveau|json_encode|raw }}
                    }
                ]
            },
            options: {
                legend: {
                    display: false
                },
                responsive: true,
                scale: {
                    reverse: false,
                    ticks: {
                        display: false,
                        maxTicksLimit: 8,
                        stepSize: 1,
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        max: 5
                    }
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Just for information, how do you display it in pdf??

Comment: follow this link: http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/250/how-to-create-a-pdf-from-html-using-knpsnappybundle-wkhtmltopdf-in-symfony-3